# how to integrate angular 4 with rails 3?

Tags: angular, ruby-on-rails-3

I have developed an application with ruby on rails 3 for five years. The application recently has many users working in, it doesn't have api and the stylesheet and design are printed with the backend. I have developed some applications with angular 4 and I love it. I would like to integrate my app made with rails to angular 4 but I don't want to redesign all the app.

Answer (score 0):

look into server side rendering with angular 4. I'm sure there are some tutorials on how to make this happen.

Comment: I think that the conflict will be when I begin developing with angular router. The rails will render these routers and my app won't be a web single page.

Comment: like i said, there are plenty of tutorials online that will show you how to compensate for this dilemma. You just need to do some research.